# Issue in configuring squid as HTTP and HTTPS transparent proxy

Tags: http, https, squid

I am doing R&D to configure Squid as HTTP and HTTPS Transparent proxy.

After some research I have configured squid HTTP and HTTPS transparent proxy and tried to start the squid but my bad luck  I am getting Fatal error when squid starts.

Here is more description about my issue,

**Issue Description**: I have installed and configured squid3.3.4 in Debian machine. To enable squid as HTTPS transparent proxy I used public signed certificate(from Godaddy) and configured the same in squid.conf file. Once the configuration done I have tried to start the squid but while starting the squid I am getting the following error.

> Error:     FATAL: No valid signing SSL certificate configured for
>   https_port 0.0.0.0:3129
>       Squid Cache (Version 3.3.4): Terminated abnormally.
>       CPU Usage: 0.020 seconds = 0.000 user + 0.020 sys
>       Maximum Resident Size: 22416 KB
>       Page faults with physical i/o: 3
>                      failed!

Note:  The certificate and private key(which is configured in squid.conf) has been converted from tomcat keystore(Godaddy certificate) file.
Squid version: 3.3.4

Someone please help me with the issue.

Here is HTTPS transparent proxy configuration in `squid.conf`:

```
http_port 3127

http_port 3128 intercept

https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid3/cert/squidtrans.pem 

key=/etc/squid3/cert/squidtrans.key

ssl_bump server-first all

sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid3/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB

sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1
```

Thanks in Advance.